# Jupyter-Notebook and d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jupyter-notebook

I would like to load a local copy of d3 into my jupyter notebook.

I have tried a variety of approaches from adding it to the config to just using the HTML function.

No approach works: (some that I have tried)

- http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/IPython/iPython_Jupyter_Notebook_with_Embedded_D3.php
  -https://github.com/ResidentMario/py_d3
- http://jarrodmcclean.com/processing-js-in-an-ipython-notebook/
- https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/issues/345
- https://mindtrove.info/4-ways-to-extend-jupyter-notebook/

Git issue: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2482

Oddly enough, a local script which has nothing more than console.log('here') works just fine (both in same directory).

How can this be done?

i.e.

```
html_string = '''
<script src="<path-to-local-dir>/d3.js"></script>
<script src="<path-to-local-dir>/test.js"></script> <!-- logs 'hi'-->
'''
HTML(html_string)
```

Comment: I've run into the same issue and used iFrame as workaround.